# How to write in custom config file from controller in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, config

I'm new to Laravel, now i'm using Laravel5 i have made custom config file now i want to write inside that from controller. So for any help and guide thanks.

Comment: for what reason down voted?

Comment: Do you just want to write all logs to a custom log file location? Or do you want log everything the standard way but in selected places log to some other file?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I want to save a link related to each record i save in table suppose i have one notification table that record notification of separate sections of my system now i want to save a link for each record category in config after that record is stored in table, i use custom config for this because if i want to change one type link i can do it easily.